# SQL Server Script generation creates objects not present

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2005  database. When I generate script for database objects, there are "unavailable" objects getting listed. And when I execute the script in new server, it always fail.

For example, following script was generated – but when I checked, the specified table is not available

```
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'create view [dbo].[xxgh08C816EF705A4D3D9534B649C0C0CAC3](guidsrc, guidlocal, pubid, generation,
            art_nick, nicknames, coldate) as select DISTINCT guidsrc, guidlocal, CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, ''F9E666B3-753C-4CBF-B1BA-3AD9E45CFFDA''), generation, art_nick, nicknames, coldate  from dbo.MSmerge_genhistory
            where guidlocal <> ''00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'' and (art_nick = 0 or art_nick is NULL or
                    art_nick in (select nickname from sysmergearticles where pubid = ''F9E666B3-753C-4CBF-B1BA-3AD9E45CFFDA''))  and ((is_srvrolemember(''sysadmin'') = 1) or (is_member(''db_owner'') = 1) or (sessionproperty(''replication_agent'') = 1))'


CHECK

SELECT * FROM dbo.MSmerge_genhistory
```

I searched a lot and it is not giving me any reference about generating script scenario. It says that it is all about `replication`.  Is there a way I can tell the script generating wizard to exclude such objects that are not really available (from a developer’s perspective) ?

Note: Please note that I do not disk space to do a backup and restore. Hence restoring with `KEEP_REPLICATION` switch manipulation is not a viable solution for me.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, if the dbo.MSmerge_genhistory table doesn't exist, you have to create it before you can create this view.  But that should be fairly obvious, and I don't understand what you're asking with regard to the script wizard or replication.   The wizard generates the scripts you ask for.  It doesn't know where you're going to deploy them, so it can't know which prerequisite objects exist or not.  Is that your question?

Comment: @TabAlleman The problem is - wizard is telling me there is a table named "dbo.MSmerge_genhistory" when I look at the generated script. But there is no such table in the source database.

Comment: Does the view work in the source database?

Comment: @TabAlleman Following command gives me result text.  `sp_helptext xxgh08C816EF705A4D3D9534B649C0C0CAC3`

Comment: I have no idea what that should be telling me.